# How to source setup.bash in ROS Window10

Tags: ros-melodic, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone. I want to install some packages on ROS Win10, I tried with choco install and it didn't work. So I tried to install from source. When I "catkin_make", it succeeded.But I don't know how to source setup.bash
By the way, I want to use multi machine with ROS_Master on Window. But I don't know how to config .bashrc file to edit ROS_MASTER_URI to make connect with other devices.
Thanks for reading

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348410/how-to-source-setup.bash-in-ros-window10/) by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 187 on 2020-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, 
On Windows 10, you can source your local workspace setup by calling `devel\setup.bat`.

To check if your local workspace is properly overlayed on top of your environment, run

```
echo %ROS_PACKAGE_PATH%
```

you should see something like this

```
C:/local_workspace/src;C:\opt\ros\melodic\x64\share
```

You should set `ROS_MASTER_URI`  as an environment variable on Windows 10. You either set it by using a GUI: open *Advanced system settings*, click the button *Environment Variables*, and add new *System variables* (different approaches to open the GUI can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)), or set it by using the [setx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) command. So if you want to permanently set `ROS_MASTER_URI`, the command would be like:

```
setx ROS_MASTER_URI “http://<ip>:11311/” /m
```

---

Originally posted by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) with karma: 241 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drtritm](https://answers.ros.org/users/50806/drtritm/) on 2020-04-05**:
Thank you so much. You save my day

**Comment by [karenchiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/48896/karenchiang/) on 2020-04-05**:
You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.

**Comment by [derobpe](https://answers.ros.org/users/63446/derobpe/) on 2020-11-16**:
Thank you both! You save my day tooooo!